# Getting a variable using tf.get_variable after graph and session is restored in new file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a model in file 1, and restore and analyze the weights in another file (file 2).

In file 1, I have created a variable using get_variable

```
with train_graph.as_default():
    softmax_wInit = tf.truncated_normal((n_vocab, n_embedding))
    softmax_w = tf.get_variable('SMWeightMatrix', initializer = softmax_wInit)
```

In file 2, I have restored the graph and session checkpoint, and attempted to get the variable using get_variable

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./MODEL4/text8.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, './MODEL4/text8.ckpt' )
  with tf.variable_scope('', reuse=True):
    embeddingRestored = tf.get_variable( 'SMWeightMatrix')
```

However, I get 'ValueError: Variable SMWeightMatrix does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?'

However, if I look into the list of variables, SMWeightMatrix is definitely there. When I run this code

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./MODEL4/text8.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, './MODEL4/text8.ckpt' )
  for v in tf.get_default_graph().get_collection("variables"):
    print(v)
  for v in tf.get_default_graph().get_collection("trainable_variables"):
    print(v)
```

This the output

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./MODEL4/text8.ckpt
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix/Adam_1:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'embedding:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'SMWeightMatrix:0' shape=(63641, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'softmax_bias:0' shape=(63641,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

I have tried using similar code in file 1 to get the variable using get_variable and have no problems

```
with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:
  with tf.variable_scope("", reuse=True):
    embeddingRestored = tf.get_variable( 'SMWeightMatrix')
```

So the issue seems related to the restoring of the graph and the session.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
tf.get_variable('MyVariableName')
```

(as you did in your example that works), not

```
tf.get_variable('MyVariableName:0')
```

which is the *output* of the variable operator, i.e its value (and the name of the tensor you will get back by calling `get_variable`).

Comment: I tried it the other way too, I still get the error "ValueError: Variable SMWeightMatrix does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?" . Also, could you elaborate by 'which is the output of the variable operator, i.e its value (and the name of the tensor you will get back by calling get_variable).' I thought output/value would be the numerical value. Sounds like it's something different. My question boils down to is, why is there a 'MyVariableName:0' AND 'MyVariableName' ?

Comment: did u get a solution to your problem ?