# Variable does not exist issue after restoring a model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I two python files File1, File2. One used to generate a tensorflow model and other other to consume the model. A problem similar to the one in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477206/getting-a-variable-using-tf-get-variable-after-graph-and-session-is-restored-in).

File1 is something like below

```
   def test():
      weights = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, vocab_size]), name="weights")}
      biases = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([vocab_size]), name="biases")}

      ...
      tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
      ....

       # Initializing the variables
      init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

      saver = tf.train.Saver()

      # Launch the graph
      with tf.Session() as session:
          session.run(init)
          .....
          while step < training_iters:
            _, acc, loss, onehot_pred = session.run([optimizer, accuracy, cost, pred], \
                                                      feed_dict={x: symbols_in_keys, y: symbols_out_onehot})
          .....
          saver.save(session, "resources/model")
```

File 2: Which restores the model is as shown below

```
   modelLocation ='resources/model.meta'
    with tf.Session().as_default() as restored_session:        
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelLocation, clear_devices=True)
        saver.restore(restored_session, modelLocation[0:len(modelLocation)-5])

        weights_restored_n = tf.get_variable("weights:0")
        biases_restored_n = tf.get_variable("biases:0")
        # weights_restored = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("weights:0")
        # biases_restored = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("biases:0")
        pred = RNN(x, weights_restored_n, biases_restored_n)
```

The error I get when I run File2 with

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (weights:0) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

if I run the file with `pred = RNN(x, weights_restored_n, biases_restored_n)` commenting the other two I get the following error

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

When I check for the available variables, I see both weights and biases variable win the restored graph.

```
<tf.Variable 'weights:0' shape=(512, 112) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'biases:0' shape=(112,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights:0' shape=(513, 2048) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/biases:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'weights/RMSProp:0' shape=(512, 112) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'weights/RMSProp_1:0' shape=(512, 112) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'biases/RMSProp:0' shape=(112,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'biases/RMSProp_1:0' shape=(112,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/RMSProp:0' shape=(513, 2048) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/RMSProp_1:0' shape=(513, 2048) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/biases/RMSProp:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/biases/RMSProp_1:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

The places where these variables are used are also set to

```
rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, reuse=True)
```

EDIT: 2nd Iteration

```
with tf.Session() as restored_session:
    modelLocation = resources/model + '.meta'       
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelLocation)
    saver.restore(restored_session, resources/model)

    # Checking what variables are present in the restored graph.
    for v in tf.get_default_graph().get_collection("variables"):
        print(v)

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    weights_restored = graph.get_tensor_by_name("weights:0")
    biases_restored = graph.get_tensor_by_name("biases:0")
    x_restored = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")

    pred = RNN(x_restored, weights_restored, biases_restored)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you are trying to reuse a pre-trained variable named "weights:0", restored from a saved `model.meta` graph file.

To do this you need to import your model and its graph definition and set it as the default graph

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('resources/model.meta')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

To get a list of all operations contained in the graph you can use `get_operations()`:

```
[op.name for op in graph.get_operations()]
```

Within the scope of the `default_graph` you can access all operations of the graph, in your case you would do something like this:

```
with graph.as_default() as default_graph:
  # get the output tensor of an operation
  weights_restored_n = default_graph.get_operation_by_name('weights').outputs[0]
  biases_restored_n = default_graph.get_operation_by_name('biases').outputs[0]
  # ... do some computations ...
  x = tf.get_variable('x') # adds a new tensor to default_graph!
  pred = RNN(x, weights_restored_n, biases_restored_n)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # restore values of 'weights:0' etc., instead of initializing
    saver.restore(sess, 'resources/model')
    # run pred operation and feed some data
    sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x:x_train})
```

I hope you get an idea how to reuse a saved meta graph and reuse trained parameters.

Note: `tf.get_variable()` adds a new tensor to the graph or reuses an existing one in the sense of a variable scope, that is different to the case of restoring a tensor and its values from a pre-trained model.

EDIT: `tf.get_tensor_by_name('weights:0')` and `tf.get_operation_by_name('weights').outputs[0]` gives the same result

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very useful . But, this did not solve my problem.  I again checked the code with the following modifications (from TF guide)  the code edit. Can you see why is it causing the error.  `ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?`

Comment: How do you call the variable `rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights`? The code above isn't showing that. Note: `foo/bar/x` is the name of a `tf.operation` of type Variable whereas `foo/bar/x:0` is the name of the output tensor of the operation you are interested in.

Comment: I have pasted the actual code on [Link](https://ybin.me/p/96edfacc2b9a7a96#grMx5gnwhE+xjBqo+df7D0qbz8SHGSFlvVVGag4DwGY=). Did not want to paste it on SO for its length. I still get the same error on the `tf.variable`

Comment: I've checked your code. You should implement the code structure shown above, especially encapsulating `graph` and `session`.



The `tf.variable_scope` encapsulation is used for sharing variables when calling functions, in the case where you build a computation graph. Here you only restore one variable. So you can just omit the encapsulation with `tf.variable_scope` in your code.